# Running Python script with scrapy import from Node child process

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, scrapy, anaconda

I'm attempting to get a simple scraper up and running to gather data and would like to use Python Scrapy. The rest of the app will be through Nodejs/Express, so I would like to call this script on demand when I need fresh/new data.

The python code runs fine locally through piecharm, but I am seeing issues when it is run as a script.

1. Through node when I run the server locally and hit /name, it fails with "no module named 'scrapy'
2. When I run the server through the Anaconda prompt this works fine and scrapy is imported with no error.
3. I have installed scrapy via conda at the location the express server is being run for both 1 and 2.

From what I've read this may have to do with scrapys need of the Twisted reactor, but as I'm new to Python it's not clear to me what the anaconda terminal is doing differently, and what I would need to do properly from the node side in order to use scrapy.

Nodejs:

```
app.get('/name', callName);
function callName(req, res) {
  console.log("test");
  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  const pyProg = spawn('python', ['pythonscript.py']);

  pyProg.stdout.on('data', function(data) {

      console.log(data.toString());
      res.write(data);
      res.end('end');
  });
}    


//Print URL for accessing server
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/')

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, () => console.log("Listening on " + (process.env.PORT || 8000)));
```

Python script:

```
try:
    import sys
    import scrapy
    data = "python starting"
    print(data)
    sys.stdout.flush()
except Exception as exception:
    print(exception, False)
    print(exception.__class__.__name__ + ": " + exception.message)
```

**Update:**
When running import scrapy from the Anaconda interpreter (the other from the comments resulted in "no module found")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy__init__.py", line 34, in 
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders__init__.py", line 10, in 
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http__init__.py", line 11, in 
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 11, in 
    import lxml.html
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lxml\html__init__.py", line 54, in 
    from .. import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

So this looks to be not just interpreter related, but perhaps something additional with Anacondas variables it uses for the terminal?

Comment: It seems just a matter of what which python environment is being used. Try to figure out exactly which python interpreter is called in anaconda shell (eg. with the command `which python`)  and spawn it using its full path from node.

Comment: You mean `where python`? I ran that and both had the same `Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe` but the anaconda shell included `Anaconda3\python.exe`

Comment: Yes. Try to start any of those interpreters using its full path and try `import scrapy`. If no error shows up, you're in the right one. Then use it in node.

Comment: @ThiagoCurvelo see updated question

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with Anaconda or Windows. But surely it is a matter of choosing the right interpreter. In the Python world, we use [virtualenvs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#using-a-virtual-environment-recommended) to solve issues like that, but I don't think it will help you because you will have to choose the right python anyways.
Try to figure out which python binary PyCharm is using.